# Additional information: Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Tags: vb.net, exception, datagridview

`total_float_hr_cnt` is a String, But values are 12, 47, 134.12 ...

```
dim critaria as string = "total_float_hr_cnt > 100"
newview.RowFilter = criteria
DataGridView1.Datasource = newview
```

And the error message is:

> Additional information: Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Pleas help.

Comment: Try changing the type of the `DataColumn` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the `DataColumn` to `Integer`